# SEO Friendly Commerce Page URLs

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

While Sitecore supports SEO Friendly URLs, the Sitecore Commerce page URLs can be quite ugly.  Is there a way to make these more SEO friendly?

Haven't been able to find any type of configuration setting or way of doing this.

here are some example URLs from the Habitat Home Demo site:

Category Page
https://experiencecommerce.habitathomedemo.com/shop/All-In-One%3dhabitat_master-all%20in%20one

Product Detail page
https://experiencecommerce.habitathomedemo.com/shop/Drones%3dhabitat_master-drones/SeekerIDrone%E2%80%9427K12MP%3d7042128

Comment: Use custom URL handling for example with the star item. Peterjustesen.com uses Commerce 9.0.2 and have SEO friendly URLs: https://peterjustesen.com/fashion/watches/guess-gent's-silver-watch-096459 (the last digits after the product name is a requirement from the customer, but can easily be removed if wanted)

Comment: So we would just create a custom LinkManager and ItemResolver to make them SEO friendly just like normal? would you happen to have code example from Peterjustesen.com?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Commerce uses own `Commerce Link Manager` for Commerce links.

```
<add name="commerce" includeFriendlyName="true" useShopLinks="true" includeCatalog="false" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="never" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" type="Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Catalog.Pipelines.CatalogLinkProvider, Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Catalog" />
```

You can play around with parameters and choose more friendly URLs configuration.

> An important note about the provider configuration properties is that
>   only 3 properties actually affect the generated URLs –
>   includeFriendlyName, useShopLinks, and encodeNames.

Configuration Properties:

- includeFriendlyName: Includes the DisplayName of the category or
  product in the URL segment. i.e. {category DisplayName}={category
  FriendlyId} and {product DisplayName}={ProductId/FriendlyId}.
- useShopLinks: Constructs URL with shop/{category}/{product} if
  enabled, otherwise as category/{category} and product/{product} for
  category and product URLs respectively.
- includeCatalog: Not currently supported
- addAspxExtension: N/A
- alwaysIncludeServerUrl: N/A
- encodeNames: Encodes the DisplayName portion of the category and
  product segments. Only supported when useShopLinks is true.
- languageEmbedding: N/A
- languageLocation: N/A
- lowercaseUrls: Not currently supported
- shortenUrls: Not currently supported
- useDisplayName: Not currently supported

For more details, I recommend Andrew  Sutherland's blog post:

http://andrewsutherland.azurewebsites.net/2018/12/17/configuring-and-customising-seo-friendly-urls-in-sitecore-commerce-sxa-storefront/